# Angular Load new Autocomplete values on each select change event

Tags: html, angular, typescript, autocomplete, angular-material

I have several most important fields in my form. In first form, user should choose the company by mat-select-search. After that, by using  (selectionChange) I'm calling API with selected value in the first field( this is company id) and return users from that company to autocomplete for recipient fields. It works perfectly, if user does not change his chosen company. But if he do that (selectionChange) method doesn't reload autocomplete with new value. There is a situation in which the user has another company selected, and autocomplete remains from the previous one. Event only loads new one if the previous output was empty. 
Is it possible to change this behavior? May be it,s possible to delete previous results from api calling?

My form :

```
  <form [formGroup]="orderForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="createOrder()">

                              <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width"  formGroupName='Company'>
                                    <mat-select ngDefaultControl  placeholder="Company" #singleSelect formControlName="id" (openedChange)="onSelectionChange($event)" [(value)]="selectedVariable">
                                    <mat-option>
                                      <ngx-mat-select-search [formControl]="companySelectFilter"  [searching]="searching" placeholderLabel="Find company..." noEntriesFoundLabel="'no matching companies found'" ></ngx-mat-select-search>
                                    </mat-option>
                                      <mat-option *ngFor="let company of filteredCompanies | async" [value]="company.id">
                                        {{company.company_name| titlecase}} {{company.company_address| titlecase}}
                                      </mat-option>
                                    </mat-select>
                                  <mat-error *ngIf="orderForm.hasError('notSame')">
                                    Recipient has another company! Select again.
                                  </mat-error>
                                  </mat-form-field>
                                </div>
                              </div>
<div class="row" matAutocompleteOrigin #origin="matAutocompleteOrigin">
                              <div class="col-md-6">

                                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" formGroupName='recipient' >

                                  <input type="text"
                                   matInput  
                                    formControlName="user_name" 
                                    placeholder="First Name" 
                                    [matAutocomplete]="auto" 
                                     [matAutocompleteConnectedTo]="origin">
                                  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="setFormData($event)">
                                    <mat-option *ngFor="let recipient of filteredOptions | async" [value]="recipient">
                                      <div style="display:flex;flex-wrap: nowrap;align-items:center;justify-content:center;margin: auto;">
                                        <span style="flex-grow: 1;flex: 1 1 33%;"> {{recipient.user_name.toString() | titlecase}} {{recipient.user_surname.toString() | titlecase}} {{recipient.company.company_name.toString() | titlecase}}
                                          </span>
                                      </div>
                                    </mat-option>
                                  </mat-autocomplete>



                                 </mat-form-field>
                              </div>

                              <div class="col-md-6" >
                                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" formGroupName='recipient'>
                                  <input matInput formControlName="user_surname"   placeholder="Last Name"[matAutocomplete]="auto"
                                          [matAutocompleteConnectedTo]="origin" >
                                          <mat-error *ngIf="orderForm.get('recipient.user_surname').hasError('required')">
                                            Last Name is <strong>required</strong>

                                          </mat-error>
                                </mat-form-field>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-6" >
                            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" formGroupName='recipient'>
                              <input matInput placeholder="Mobile Phone" type="text" formControlName="user_telephone" >
                            </mat-form-field>
                          </div>
```

OnSelected change method:

```
  onSelectionChange(opened: boolean) {
    console.log(`opened is : ${opened}`);
    if (!opened && this.selectedVariable) {

      this.orderForm.get('recipient.user_name').reset()
      this.orderForm.get('recipient.user_surname').reset()
      this.orderForm.get('recipient.user_telephone').reset()

      this.filteredOptions = this.orderForm
        .get('recipient.user_name')
      .valueChanges.pipe(
        startWith(""),
        debounceTime(400),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        switchMap((val) => {
          return this.doFilter(this.selectedVariable, val || '');
        })
      );
          }
  }
```

And doFilter method :

```
doFilter(id: number, val: any): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.recipientService.getRecipientsByCompany(id).pipe(
      map((response) =>
        response.filter((option) => {
          return (
            option.user_name
              .toString()
              .toLowerCase()
              .indexOf(val.toString().toLowerCase()) === 0 ||
            option.user_surname
              .toString()
              .toLowerCase()
              .indexOf(val.toString().toLowerCase()) === 0
          );
        })
      )
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution. My mistake was I trying to retrieve the data from API after page loaded. Now, I load all the recipients in NgOnInit method and filter the data after user change the company.

LoadRecipients method which we put into ngOnInit:

```
    this.recipientService
      .getRecipientsObs()
      .subscribe((recipients) => (this.recipients = recipients));
  }
```

And new OnChange method :

```
selectedVariable: any;
  onSelectionChange(opened: boolean) {
    console.log(`opened is : ${opened}`);
    console.log(this.selectedVariable)
    if (!opened && this.selectedVariable) {
      this.orderForm.get("recipient.user_name").reset();
      this.orderForm.get("recipient.user_surname").reset();
      this.orderForm.get("recipient.user_telephone").reset();
      const formsInput = merge(
        this.orderForm.get('recipient.user_name').valueChanges,
        this.orderForm.get('recipient.user_surname').valueChanges
      );
     formsInput.pipe(
        startWith(""),
        debounceTime(400),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        map((search) => {
          if (!this.recipients) {
            return [];
          } else {
            search = search.toLowerCase();
          }

          return this.recipients.filter(
            (recipient) =>
              recipient.company.id === this.selectedVariable &&
              recipient.user_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1 &&
              recipient.user_surname.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1 
          );
        }),
        delay(500)
      )
      .subscribe(
        (filteredRecipients) => {
          this.searching = false;
          this.filteredRecipients.next(filteredRecipients);
        },
        (error) => {
          this.searching = false;
        }
      );
    }
  }
```